# Odoo - Many2one implementation in database

Tags: odoo-10

While debugging a module I have the need to inspect a many2one field directly in postgres.

How can I find the *account_move* rows in database that belong to a given *hr_expense_sheet* row? Is *ir_model_data* table used to implement the many2one relation?

```
class HrExpenseSheet(models.Model):
....
    account_move_id = fields.Many2one('account.move', string='Journal Entry', copy=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really provide quite enough information for me to know the exact relationships between each of the models, but here's a general idea.

> Is ir_model_data table used to implement the many2one relation?

The `Many2one` relation is managed with a [foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). So, on the `HrExpenseSheet` model, it stores the `account_move_id` as an ID. If you want the `AccountMove` information directly from the database, you must search the `account_move` for that given ID.

Assuming the models a related something like this:

```
class AccountMove(models.Model):
    _inherit = "account.move"
    ...

class HrExpense(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.expense"
    ...

class HrExpenseSheet(models.Model):
    _inherit = "hr.expense.sheet"

    account_move_id = fields.Many2one('account.move', string='Journal Entry', copy=False)
    expense_id = fields.Many2one('hr.expense', string='Expense', copy=False)
```

Basically, the query you will run is going to find all account moves for any line that belongs to a given expense.

```
SELECT * FROM account_move WHERE id IN (
    SELECT account_move_id FROM hr_expense_sheet WHERE expense_id = 123);
```

If you just want to find for a specific `HrExpenseSheet`, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM account_move WHERE id = 123;
```

Comment: I found that account_move_id is implemented as a column table hence sql applied is the one you suggest.